# (linux) gzip fails with No space left on device

Tags: linux, gzip

I need to compress a directory on my Ubuntu server. The directory is about 3.2 Go, and I have 15 Go left over 20 Go available on my server. 
I'm using the command: `tar -zcvf test src_directory`

The command fails with the message:

> gzip: stdout: No space left on device
>   tar: test: Wrote only 6144 of 10240 bytes
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Why is it failing as I have enough space on my server ? (15 Go should be enough)

thanks

**EDIT**

```sh
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            463M     0  463M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  2.2M   96M   3% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G   17G  2.2G  89% /
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            24K     0   24K   0% /var/gandi
```

```sh
$ lsblk 
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0     0   20G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1     0   20G  0 part /
xvdz    202:6400  0  512M  0 disk 
├─xvdz1 202:6401  0  502M  0 part [SWAP]
└─xvdz2 202:6402  0   10M  0 part
```

with df, I can see there is only 2.2G left on the disk. How can I have details about what is taking so much space ? Because I know that my application files only take 4.6G.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enough memory available on the partition you want the archive to be stored in

```sh
$: df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          476G  300G  176G  63% /
```

Also check if you have the permissions necessary to archive the desired directory.

If the problem still persists, I may suggest a filesystem check

```
$: lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0   5.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0    50G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 642.4G  0 part /home

# Find the device that matches the mountpoint of the directory in question
# Replace X with the appropriate device
# Replace Y with the appropriate partition
$: sudo fsck -vcck /dev/sdXY
```

Comment: Additionally, there could also be a disk quota set for the user, installing the `quota` package and running `sudo repquota /` would show this.

Comment: Thanks, please have a look at my EDIT.